# How to outline border of the slicer in Power BI Desktop

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-embedded

How can I outline the border of the slicer?
I want to change color of the border of the window where it says "All".

[image]

I do not need like this:

[image]

I need something like that"

[image]

Anyway to achieve that in Power bi?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is currently possible with the built-in slicer.

To do this, you'll either have to [create your own custom visual](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-Visuals) or else [submit an idea](https://ideas.powerbi.com) and hope it gets implemented.

---

This image shows the different pieces you can currently adjust.

[image: Borders]

Notice that the border for the header and the items (purple) is the same thickness and color, the outside border (yellow) can't be changed in width, and the Items Outline doesn't display except on the drop-down section.

---

You could make a really thick border using the Background, but I don't think that's a good option.

[image: Thick Border]